# mod_rewrite rule for redirecting url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out a mod_rewrite rule to redirect from the following URL:

/archives/collections/archon/index.php?p=collections/controlcard&id=450

to this:

/archives/collections/archon/index.php?p=collections/findingaid&id=450

The id parameter would not be static.

Thanks for any help.

Current contents of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=collections/controlcard&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?p=collections/controlcard&id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%{QUERY_STRING}` you can do it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /archives/collections/archon/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=collections/controlcard&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?p=collections/findingaid&id=%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: @codeman Doesn't work as in? Also do u have other rules on your htaccess? do you have multiple .htaccess files or just 1 on the root folder?

Comment: Doesn't work as far as its not redirecting to anything. No other rules in the .htaccess. This .htaccess is not in the root, it's in the archon directory, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it can be the problem as the rule would be different, see update and let me know if it works

Comment: The update you gave now redirects, but it's actually appending the local systems htdocs path like: /data/htdocs/archives/collections/....

Comment: @codeman post your htaccess so I can see what may be the issue. It's possible that some rule is conflicting or something is missing like RewriteBase.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=collections/controlcard&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?p=collections/controlcard&id=%1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `archon/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /archon/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=collections/controlcard(&.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|)$ $1?p=collections/findingaid%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```